# Is it sufficient to trigger notifyUpdateCell() or is it necessary to trigger clearAllCachedResultValues()

Tags: java, apache-poi

Our application is heavily using Apache POI. For Performance reasons we are caching the `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator` instances after creation. The javadoc states that it is necessary to call `clearAllCachedResultValues()` if cell value changes

> if any workbook cells are changed between calls to evaluate~ methods on this class.

I've noticed that the interface also contains other methods like `notifyUpdateCell(Cell cell)`.

Is there a performance or any other benefit of triggering `notifyUpdateCell(Cell cell)` (for each Cell I update) vs. `clearAllCachedResultValues()` before executing formula evaluation? Note: we don't add/remove any cells, we are just setting cell values and cell types.

Comment: You either need to call `notifyUpdateCell` for *every* cell you changed before you re-evaluate, or you have to throw away the whole cache with `clearAllCachedResultValues` + start again. Do you know what cells you're changing?

Comment: See also http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html#Performance

Comment: Yes I know all the cells that I'm changing. I was just wondering if it is sufficient / advisable to go with `notifyUpdateCell` instead of `clearAllCachedResultValues `  (e.g. because it might be faster to just clear all the caches once instead of triggering `notifyUpdateCell` a hundred times.)

Comment: For a big / complex workbook, `notifyUpdateCell` is faster

Comment: @Gagravarr do you want to convert your comment to an answer then I'll aaccept it

Comment: Use clearAllCachedResultValues(); Look stackoverflow.com/a/60559846/715269

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the [POI Formula Evaluation docs in the Performance section](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html#Performance), the `FormulaEvaluator` will cache evaluations of dependent cells, so if you have multiple formulas all depending on a cell, then subsequent evaluations will be faster.

If you make some changes to the spreadsheet after you've started evaluation, then you've got two choices. One is just to clear all the caches on the evaluator, so it re-computes all needed dependencies again. That's done via [clearAllCachedResultValues()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html#clearAllCachedResultValues%28%29). If you only have simple formulas, or not many formulas, or formulas which rarely depend on other formula cells, it could be quicker + will certainly be easier for you.

Otherwise, use the `notify*Cell` family of methods, eg [notifyUpdateCell(Cell)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html#notifyUpdateCell%28org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell%29), to tell the evaluator to just ditch the cache for anything depending on that one cell. All unaffected cell caches will remain, so complex formula evaluations will be quicker as the caches will still be there. However, this approach do require you to know exactly which cells you changed, so it's a bit more advanced.

Comment: We went for the solution to trigger notfiyUpdateCell for each cell we change and so far it looks good in our testing